# Why is my floating container going under my div rather than starting on a new line

Tags: html, css

My `page-button-container` is not start on a new like even though i am using `display: block`. it is going under my `test-pics-container`. Why is this and how can I fix it? I figured out that if I reload `float: right` from my `page-button-container` it works (but then its not floating to the right.

I want it to look something like this:

[image]

```css
.test-lookup-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 26px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: purple;
}

.page-buttons-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  background-color: orange;
}

.test-pics-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 900px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0 26px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
}

.test-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-lookup-container">
  <div class="page-buttons-container">
    ssssssssssssssss
  </div>
  <div class="test-pics-container">
    <div class="test-item">
      <img alt="" src="test.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @connexo edited, and added a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear floating element `<div style="clear: both;" ></div>`

```css
.test-lookup-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 26px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: purple;
}

.page-buttons-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  background-color: orange;
}

.test-pics-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 900px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0 26px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
}

.test-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-lookup-container">
  <div class="page-buttons-container">
    ssssssssssssssss
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;" ></div>
  <div class="test-pics-container">
    <div class="test-item">
      <img alt="" src="test.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The clear property specifies on which sides of an element floating elements are not allowed to float here we passed "both" that means floating elements are not allowed on both side, so the new element starts from next line

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add the following rule.

```
.test-pics-container { overflow: hidden; }
```

But if `overflow` property hides some content, that is positioned outside of `.test-pics-container`, you can use "clearfix" approach.

```
.clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; clear: both; }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<div class="test-pics-container clearfix">
   ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use float to create layouts, it has so many problems a beginner cannot understand or deal with.

Is this what you want to create?

```css
.test-lookup-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 26px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: purple;
}

.page-buttons-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: orange;
  right: 0;
  top: -70px;
}

.test-pics-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 900px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0 26px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.test-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-lookup-container">
  <div class="test-pics-container">
    <div class="page-buttons-container">
      page-buttons-container
    </div>
    <div class="test-item">
      test-item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know how I can do it with absolute, but I don't want ti make a website using absolute. Using absolute is very easy, but I want to move onto the harder stuff

Comment: Absolute position is not recommended for creating columns. To make it work you always have to be sure, that the statically positioned column is higher (has bigger height), than the absolutely positioned one.